# Guardar datos en Json con javascript

Tags: json

Buenas tengo un archivo comments.json que contiene lo sguiente:

```
{
    "comments": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "post_id": 2,
            "name": "Javi",
            "email": "j_alonso_78@hotmail.com",
            "body": "Esto es un post",
            "created_at": "2017-12-29"    
        },
        {
             "id": 2,
            "post_id": 1,
            "name": "Pepe",
            "email": "pepe@gmail.com",
            "body": "Otro post de pepe",
            "created_at": "2017-12-29" 
        }
    ]
}
```

Como puedo añadir a este archivo lo siguiente:

```
{
             "id": 3,
            "post_id": 1,
            "name": "Juan",
            "email": "juan@gmail.com",
            "body": "nuevo post",
            "created_at": "2017-12-29" 
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

¡Hola! No creo que sea buena política usar un archivo .json gestionado manualmente como base de datos, te recomendaría usar algún SQL o noSQL (Firebase guarda en Json por ejemplo).

De cualquier forma si es indispensable hacerlo de esta forma puedes hacer lo siguiente (escrito en php, pero en cualquier lenguaje se puede hacer lo mismo):

```
$contenido = file_get_contents('path/to/comments.json');
$contenido_arr = json_decode($contenido, true);
$contenido_arr['comments'][] = [
"id" => 3,
"post_id" => 1,
"name" => "Juan",
"email" => "juan@gmail.com",
"body" => "nuevo post",
"created_at" => "2017-12-29" 
];
$json = json_encode($contenido_arr);
file_put_contents('path/to/comments.json', $json);
```

Debo insistir en que no recomendaría hacer esto, salvo que sea absolutamente necesario.
¡Saludos y suerte!